# How do I find the total number of lines in a set of found files (using Linux command-line tools)?

Tags: linux, find, command-line-interface

I can find the number of lines of each file matching a particular pattern using (for example):

```
$ find . -name "test.save*" -exec wc -l {} \;
673000 ./test.save8.txt
24000 ./from/test1/test.save3.txt
100 ./from/test1/test.save1.txt
513000 ./from/test1/test.save2.txt
2253000 ./from/test1/test.save4.txt
2252000 ./from/test2/test.save3.txt
100 ./from/test2/test.save1.txt
596000 ./from/test2/test.save2.txt
2224000 ./from/test3/test.save3.txt
100 ./from/test3/test.save1.txt
593000 ./from/test3/test.save2.txt
270000 ./from/test4/test.save3.txt
100 ./from/test4/test.save1.txt
332234 ./from/test4/test.save2.txt
2177000 ./from/test4/test.save4.txt
1728000 ./test.save3.txt
180000 ./test.save1.txt
466000 ./test.save11.txt
233000 ./test.save9.txt
686880 ./test.save5.txt
215262 ./test.save7.txt
2560000 ./test.save12.txt
18080 ./test.save10.txt
432000 ./test.save2.txt
10000 ./test.save4.txt
684000 ./test.save6.txt
```

How do I add up all the individual numbers (using Linux command-line tools)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
find ... -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```

If your version of `find` supports it, this will be *much* faster:

```
find ... -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

or if you want both the individual counts and the total:

```
find ... | xargs wc -l
```

The first two will handle filenames with spaces. In order to make the last one above work if there are filenames with spaces, use `-print0` and `-0`:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Comment: That does not sum up the total number of lines it just prints out what he already has.

Comment: The second command works great.  The first is *very* slow.  (I'm still waiting for it to complete.)  Perhaps you should just remove it from your answer.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the first command works, since I'm still waiting for it to complete.

Comment: @Daryl: Double check to see if you ran the first version I posted that didn't have the curly braces. Without them, it doesn't work. With them, it does. Also, change the `\;` to `+` - it will speed up considerably. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: I was running the version without curly braces.  It works with curly braces.  The version with `+` works on Ubuntu 10, but (for me) isn't any faster.

Comment: Why `find ...` instead of `find .` with only one `.`?

Comment: @solvingPuzzles: The ellipsis represents omitted information to the reader (rather than anything specific to the computer).

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant but this would do

```
#!/bin/bash
#
total=0
for value in $(find . -name "test.save*" -exec wc -l {} \;|awk '{ print $1 }'); do
let total=total+value
done
echo $total
```

Comment: Is this meant to be run as a shell script?  Can you add the appropriate shebang?

Comment: I can't figure out how to execute this.

Comment: Of course thats meant to be run from the shell, if you want to turn it to a script you will have to add the shebang. The value you want will be in $total.

So what do you mean you cannot figure out how to execute this ?

Comment: Which shell?  If I paste this into a bash command line (on Ubuntu), I get: "The program 'total' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install radiance"

Comment: The spaces need to be removed from the "total = 0" line.  And you'll need to `echo $total` to see what the actual total is.

Comment: okay converted to script now you can create a script, chmod a+x then run it.

Comment: It will fail if any filenames have spaces in them. Also, you can do `let total+=value` or `(( total += value ))`

Answer (score 2):

You can take your original solution and pipe into a summing program in awk:

```
find . -name "test.save*" -exec wc -l {} \; | \
  awk '{count += $1} END {print count}'
```